# Entity Framework pulling null in three tables

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have three tables in my database. Every table works with different Entity Class, the code:

```
public class Quizs
{
    [Key]
    public int QuizId { get; set; }            
    public string Title { get; set; }    
    public string Instructions { get; set; }    
    public string IsTimerEnabled { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }    
    public int RightAnswer { get; set; } // Key of Answers[]    
    public int QuestionType { get; set; } // 1 = One choise, 2 = Multiple Choise    
    public string Explantion { get; set; } // To appear after answering the question    
    public int MaxTime { get; set; } // In seconds
}

public class Answers
{
    [Key]
    public int asId { get; set; }    
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

So now i need to output all the data in this three tables to the WebApi page.

Here is the code that pulling out the data in the controller:

```
// GET api/QuizsData/
    public IEnumerable<Quizs> Get()
    {

        return dba.Quiz.Include("Questions").Include("Questions.Answers").ToList();
    }
```

This is what I get when I go to the route of the api:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid column
>   name 'Question_QuestionId'.\r\nInvalid column name
>   'Question_QuestionId'.","ExceptionType":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)"}

I got this Exception Message.. any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect a `Quizs` to have only one question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you've set up your relationships the way you think you have.

Try these *changes*:

```
public class Quizs
{
    // no attribute
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    // no attribute
    public virtual ICollection<Answers> Answers { get; set; }

    // add
    [ForeignKey("Quiz")]
    public int QuizId { get; set; }
    public virtual Quizs Quiz { get; set; }
}

public class Answers
{
    // add
    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

(Also, consider turning your class names to singular. It'll make for less semantic confusion.)

---

A little more explanation on what's what:

What you're trying to achieve here is called a **one-to-many relationship**. For example, you have many questions pointing to one quiz. Or you have many answers pointing to one question. In the quiz-question relationship, the quiz is the "one" side and the question is the "many" side. In the question-answer relationship, the question is the "one" side and the answer is the "many" side.

To achieve such a relationship in Entity Framework, all you have to do is go to the **"many" side** of the relationship and add something like this:

```
public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
```

And then go to the **"one" side** of the relationship and add something like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

Entity Framework understands that the first declaration means "create a foreign key to the table `Quiz`" and the other means "multiple records of the `Question` table will point here".

This works just like the relationships between normal classes, except that you make the properties *virtual* so that the Entity Framework can override them at runtime with a property that actually implements this relationship.

As things are now, from your ("many" side) model you have no access to the foreign key created in the database. You do have access to the record it refers to, *but not to the foreign key itself* (at least not without fetching the other record). To fix this, you can tell the Entity Framework **to use an explicitly declared property as the foreign key**, like this:

```
[ForeignKey("Quiz")]
public int QuizId { get; set; }
```

The `ForeignKey` attribute says that the following `int` property (`QuizId`) will be the actual foreign key used by the property `Quiz`, instead of letting it implicitly create its own foreign key in the table that would be inaccessible to us.

To put it another way: a foreign key was going to be created anyway, since you referenced another model. The attribute is there to denote that you want to have access to that foreign key yourself. In most cases, you'll want this.

Comment: Still, this is the body: [{"QuizId":1,"Title":"tesxt text","Instructions":"rasdad sadad ad","IsTimerEnabled":"false","Questions":null}]

Questions: null, the same problem..

this is the new code: http://pastebin.com/1q54ikW0

Answer (score 1):

With entity framework you can [eager load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) child entities:

```
 return dba.Quiz.Include("Questions").Include("Questions.Answers").ToList();
```

Or with lambda syntax (will not break if you will rename property again):

```
 return dba.Quiz.Include(q => q.Questions.Select(x => x.Answers)).ToList();
```

See remarks on [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method to understand its syntax.

---

Also you should fix your key on `Answer` entity. It should be `asId` because you are using `Id` as foreign key for question (weird naming btw):

```
public class Answers
{
    [Key]
    public int asId { get; set; }  // use this property as PK
    public int Id { get; set; }  // because this is FK
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I get an exception message: http://pastebin.com/XRzLmYTV
the columns are stored in the database as it is, but the sql server can't found it.. What is the problem?

Comment: @DanielChernenkov there was misprint in property name, fixed. Should work now

Comment: i have edited the post, can you please check my code again as it edited? maybe something in my changes creates this Exception message.. (your fix not worked)

Comment: @DanielChernenkov you renamed property `Answer` to `Answers`. Simply write correct property path in include method. I'll update sample

Comment: Now i have new exception: "Invalid column name 'Questions_QuestionId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Question_QuestionId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Questions_QuestionId'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Question_QuestionId'."

I change the collection to single: public virtual Question Questions { get; set; }

Comment: @DanielChernenkov then you changed something again. I've copy-pasted your **current code from question** and checked it - works without any problems.

Comment: Oh, my bad. i found my mistake with one letter. great! thanks.

Comment: @DanielChernenkov it's better to use lambda-based syntax to avoid such mistakes - compiler will tell you if some property name or type will change

Answer (score 0):

Use Include method for eager loading related entities, like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232